# How to use a Service into a web component

Tags: angular, web-component

I'm trying to make an angular web component by following this guide:
https://www.codementor.io/blog/angular-web-components-8e4n0r0zw7

It works but when I have to inject `services` into my component, nothing works anymore, if I write (`private service: DataService`) in the constructor I have a blank screen and no console errors.

```
import {Component, Injector, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../../_service/data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'optix-calendar',
  templateUrl: './optix-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./optix-calendar.component.scss']
})
export class OptixCalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() apiKey = null;

  token = null;

  formData = {name: '', email: ''};
  formSubmitted = false;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    this.formSubmitted = true;
  }
```

and this is app.module:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {NgModule, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {createCustomElement} from '@angular/elements';
import {OptixCalendarComponent} from './optix-calendar/optix-calendar.component';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [OptixCalendarComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule, MatInputModule, MatCardModule

    ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [OptixCalendarComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    const el = createCustomElement(OptixCalendarComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('optix-calendar', el);
  }

  ngDoBootstrap(): void {
  }
}
```

Can you point me in the right direction in order to use a Service in my web component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor(injector: Injector) {}

 ngDoBootstrap(): void {
    const el = createCustomElement(OptixCalendarComponent, {injector});
    customElements.define('optix-calendar', el);
  }
```

And remove the selector from your component:

```
@Component({
 // selector: 'optix-calendar',
  templateUrl: './optix-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./optix-calendar.component.scss']
})
```

I think you are exporting an angular application not a web component: you call optix-calendar instead of app-root.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shocked that the wrong answer was chosen as the correct one!
The real reason is quite simple - you need to load the HttpClientModule into the AppModule itself.

Because you have used services, so you should have used HttpClient right, or related modules, so any modules used must be loaded into the AppModule inside, such as HttpClient, you can do the following:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
....
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ....
  ],
  imports: [
    ....
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  entryComponents: [....],
})
```

Another example is the use of non-module functions, such as using DatePipe, then similarly, write it into providers, such as:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ....
  ],
  imports: [
    ....
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [ DatePipe ],
  entryComponents: [....],
})
```

So that it works properly, hope this helps you to find out what the problem is.